# Sharing part of a branch with another branch

Tags: git

Let's say you have two public feature branches, `feature1` and `feature2`. 
The workflow in question that public feature branches are considered "integration" branches.
Each of these two branches are being worked on by two different developers, minding their own business. 
One day, the developer of `feature1` realizes that he needs some of the code in `feature2`. What is the best way of going about this. 
Let's assume the code in question can be cherry-picked because each commit was focused enough so that they only refer exactly to the code in question.

My gut feeling, however, is that cherry picking the commits will lead to problems later down the line, since they have different SHA1s. It will also (I think), lose the original author info.

Is there a better way of going about this?

Comment: This is one of the reasons why you should have separate feature branch for each feature. If you had that branch for the code that's needed, you could simply merge it. Am I right that this is not the case in your repo?

Comment: There is a separate branch for each feature. The problem is feature1 requires some code from feature2.

Comment: Then you should probably split your features into smaller parts and have a branch for each of them. But that won't help you right now.

Comment: I guess my ultimate question is, will cherry-picking lead me into trouble later on

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, `git cherry-pick` doesn't lose information about the original author, that stays the same. It does lose information about the commiter, but that's correct.

Now, git is pretty clever when it comes to merging, so I think you should have no problems when you cherry-pick the commits you want. But if you want to make sure, you can always try it out on a temporary branch (or in a temporary copy of the repo).